# Using java Pattern and Matcher, how to get first matching tag content

Tags: java, regex

I have at SoapMessage that looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://service.xxx.dk/DialogModtag</Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:382b4943-26e8-4698-a275-c3149d2d889e</MessageID>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://xxx.dk/12345678</To>
    <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:cb2320dc-c8ab-4880-94cb-2ab68129216f</RelatesTo>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2515">
    Some content ...
</soap:Body>
```

and I am trying to extract the contents of the <Action> tag within the <Header> tag using code like this:

```
Pattern PATTERN_SOAP_ACTION = 
    Pattern.compile(".*Header.*Action.*>(.*)<.*Action.*Header.*", Pattern.DOTALL);

String text = readFile("c:\\temp\\DialogUdenBilag.xml");
Matcher matcherSoapAction = PATTERN_SOAP_ACTION.matcher(text);
if (matcherSoapAction.matches()) { System.out.println(matcherSoapAction.group(1)); }
else { System.out.println("SaopAction not found"); }
```

This seems to be working OK for small soap messages. But when the soap:Body grows to +1MB, then the matches() function call takes minutes to complete.

Any ideas for making my regex pattern more CPU friendly?

Comment: Possible answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

You want to use an XML parser for a more CPU friendly solution.

```
 XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
 XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\DialogUdenBilag.xml"));

 boolean found=false;
 boolean inHeader=false;
 String actionContent = "";

 while(!found && reader.hasNext()){
    if(reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        String localName=reader.getLocalName());

        if ("Header".equalsIgnoreCase(localName) {
            inHeader = true;
        }

        if(inHeader && "Action".equalsIgnoreCase(localName) {

            int evt=reader.next();
            do {
               if (evt==XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
                   actionContent = reader.getText().trim();
                   found=true;
                   break;
               }

               evt=reader.next();
            } while(evt != XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT);

        }
    }
 }

 if (found) {
     System.out.println(actionContent);
 } else {
     System.out.println("SaopAction not found");
 }
```

#### Discussion

This little snippet is a little bit lengthy but you'll get your answer **without looking inside the whole** XML code. In fact, the snippet stops when it find the `soap:Action` tag and then returns the text content of this tag.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I want to use your solution, which even also works much quicker for small soap actions.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions to parse XML is evil, and [may incur the Wrath of the One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)  If you need to parse XML, use an actual XML parser - that's what it's there for.  And situations like this are what XPath expressions are for, too:

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContextMap(
    "s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "a", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"));
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//s:Header/a:Action");
String result = expression.evaluate(new org.xml.sax.InputSource(new FileReader("c:\\temp\\DialogUdenBilag.xml")));
```

(Note that `NamespaceContextMap` isn't a standard class - see [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html) for the implementation.)

---

As for your regexp: it's written to unnecessarily match the entire input string, and doing lots of maximal rather than minimal matching.  You'd chew through a lot less CPU if you had an expression more tightly focused on just the relevant bit of the document (for example, `"<((?:\\w+:)?)?Header\\b[^>]*>.*?<((?:\\w+:)?)Action\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\2Action>.*?</\\1Header>"`), and called `Matcher.find()` to do a substring match.  That said, parsing XML with a regexp is bad practice - you really should be using an XML parser instead!